# reading Git Commit Log file for any project

Tags: java, git

i am new to use Git, and Want to do analysis of any git commit log file.
So want to read/ load the commit log history file from Git for any project using java.
is there any standard way to doing this or any suggestion/approach to do this.

Comment: Do you have multiple Git repositories,  that may or may not be Java projects?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **JGit**. JGit is a "lightweight, pure Java library implementing the Git version control system".
See: http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/

You may also want to have a look at **jagged**. jagged is an experimental java bindings to libgit2: jagged provides Java language bindings to libgit2, a native Git implementation.
See:
https://github.com/ethomson/jagged
and:
https://libgit2.github.com/